# C# class overwrite possibility

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having a question, and probably it can not be done this way but maybe there is some other way i do not know, so I have a class that looks like this:

```
    [DataContract] 
    public class Parent 
    {
        [DataMember(Name="id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "value")]
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Now this class is a attribute value of different class:

```
    [DataContract] 
    public class Location 
    {
        [DataMember(Name="parent")]
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

But there is a catch, I need separate classes bout same type for example:

```
    [DataContract] 
    public class Parent 
    {
        [DataMember(Name="id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    } 

    [DataContract] 
    public class Parent 
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "value")]
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Depending if Value is null or not (and I need this to be separate object cause as you see I want to map this). Is it possible to overwrite class so one class can have one or other attribute only?

Comment: As far as creating contracts goes... wouldn't it be sufficient to have a single `Parent` class with BOTH properties, but mark those properties as **nullable**?

Comment: If both classes represent different things (which they do as they have totally different members) they should also have different names. There is no way (and no reason) to use the same name for different classes as long as they reside in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it with inheritance, but IMHO it gets overdesigned.

Personally, I would all put into the Parent class. Make the properties nullable, than it's done. If you want to have some reliability that at least one property is set, you may want to make the setters private (given that you don't need to change them after creating the parent) and have factory methods to create parents with an Id or a Value.

Parent with encapsulation (if required):

```
[DataContract] 
public class Parent 
{
    private Parent() {}

    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int? Id { get; private set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public int? Value { get; private set; }

    public static Parent CreateWithId(int id)
    {
        return new Parent { Id = id };
    }

    public static Parent CreateWithValue(int value)
    {
        return new Parent { Value = value };
    }
}
```

You can further add a ParentType property which returns an enum value which is either ParentType.ValueParent or ParentType.IdParent. Again, this is only useful when required, e.g. because it simplifies handling of parents, when there is a chance to get more different types or when you may want to support Id Parents with a null value as Id or the same with the Value.

---

Completely different solution is to store both Id and Value in the same property, since both are integers. Have another way to distinguish wether it is a Id or a Value.

```
[DataContract] 
public class Parent 
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int Data { get; private set; }

    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public ParentType ParentType { get; private set; }

    public static Parent CreateWithId(int id)
    {
        return new Parent { Data = id, ParentType = ParentType.Id };
    }

    public static Parent CreateWithValue(int value)
    {
        return new Parent { Data = value, ParentType = ParentType.Value };
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to represent DIFFERENT data by creating two different classes which are named the same. This is an error. Initially I wanted to suggest using interfaces or inheritance, but that makes no sense, as both `Parent` classes you wrote contain different things and there's no overlap.

If this case is directed purely because you need to map those properties to some data contract, then why not have a `Parent` class with both properties and just make those properties `Nullable`?

Something along the lines:

```
[DataContract] 
public class Parent 
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1  As said HimBromBree, you can put Parent classes in different namespaces.

WCF also allows you to provide different names for Serialization of classes through `[DataContract]` attribute :

```
[DataContract(Name="ParentA")]
public class Parent { 
  [DataMember(Name="id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

2 If your goal is to have Parent class to hold different values (Value or Id) depending on circumstances, you can also create two derived classes of Parent.

Let's call those classes ParentA and ParentB

Then on Parent, you should make a declaration for polymorphic serialization :

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ParentA))]
[KnownType(typeof(ParentB))]
public class Parent  {}


[DataContract(Name="ParentA")]
public class ParentA : Parent { 
  [DataMember(Name="id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```